# FEN (Chess notation) to HTML generator? Open source Java

Tags: java, android, html, open-source, chess

Before we implement our own, is there an existing Open Source piece of Java code that takes a chess [FEN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth-Edwards_Notation) string and converts it into an HTML representation of the chess board?

A FEN code looks like this: `rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1`

The output would be something like `<table><tr><td>♘</td><td>♛</td><td>...`

An icons-based solution, or even a solution that produces a big image instead of HTML, could be acceptable too. It is for integration into an Android app.

*([Here is an implementation in Python](http://uucode.com/blog/2011/06/27/chess-fen-plugin-for-anki/))*

Comment: Why images? Aren't chess symbols part of Unicode?

Comment: @KerrekSB: Indeed! That would be fine as well. Updating my question.

Comment: Hm, there seems to be a good LaTeX package ("skak"), and there's always LaTeX2HTML, but that seems wasteful. A direct-to-HTML solution would be nice.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Thanks! Android does not understand LaTeX unfortunately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found some useful CSS3 from this place: http://designindevelopment.com/css/css3-chess-board/
So I came up with the following:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .chess_board { border:1px solid #333; }
        .chess_board td {
            background:#fff; background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #eee);
            background:-webkit-gradient(linear,0 0, 0 100%, from(#fff), to(#eee));
            box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 1px #fff;
            -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 1px #fff;
            -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 1px #fff;
            height:40px; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; width:40px; font-size:30px;}
        .chess_board tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(even),
        .chess_board tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(odd) {
            background:#ccc; background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #ccc, #eee);
            background:-webkit-gradient(linear,0 0, 0 100%, from(#ccc), to(#eee));
            box-shadow:inset 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
            -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
            -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.4); }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function renderFen(fentxt) {
            fentxt = fentxt.replace(/ .*/g, '');
            fentxt = fentxt.replace(/r/g, 'x'); // Convert black rooks to 'x' to avoid mixup with <tr></tr> tags
            fentxt = fentxt.replace(/\//g, '</tr><tr>');
            fentxt = fentxt.replace(/1/g, '<td></td>');
            fentxt = fentxt.replace(/2/g, '<td></td><td></td>');
            fentxt = fentxt.replace(/3/g, '<td></td><td></td><td></td>');
            fentxt = fentxt.replace(/4/g, '<td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>');
            fentxt = fentxt.replace(/5/g, '<td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>');
            fentxt = fentxt.replace(/6/g, '<td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>');
            fentxt = fentxt.replace(/7/g, '<td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>');
            fentxt = fentxt.replace(/8/g, '<td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>');
            fentxt = fentxt.replace(/K/g, '<td>&#9812;</td>');
            fentxt = fentxt.replace(/Q/g, '<td>&#9813;</td>');
            fentxt = fentxt.replace(/R/g, '<td>&#9814;</td>');
            fentxt = fentxt.replace(/B/g, '<td>&#9815;</td>');
            fentxt = fentxt.replace(/N/g, '<td>&#9816;</td>');
            fentxt = fentxt.replace(/P/g, '<td>&#9817;</td>');
            fentxt = fentxt.replace(/k/g, '<td>&#9818;</td>');
            fentxt = fentxt.replace(/q/g, '<td>&#9819;</td>');
            fentxt = fentxt.replace(/x/g, '<td>&#9820;</td>');
            fentxt = fentxt.replace(/b/g, '<td>&#9821;</td>');
            fentxt = fentxt.replace(/n/g, '<td>&#9822;</td>');
            fentxt = fentxt.replace(/p/g, '<td>&#9823;</td>');
            return '<table class="chess_board" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr>' + fentxt + '</tr></table>';
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write(renderFen('rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1'));
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from Alexander Maryanovsky Jin's [site](http://www.jinchess.com/) site:

> **About Jin**
>
> Jin is an open source, cross platform, graphical client for chess
>   servers, written in **Java**. Jin can run either as a standalone
>   application (available at this website) or as an applet, directly from
>   your browser (available at the chess server's website).

His project is open source and available on [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jin/).

Grab the `Position.java` class and you will find some piece of Java code handling FEN.

Comment: +1 I already accepted an answer, but the fact that Jin is in Java makes it a closer answer to my written question (even though in my particular use case JavaScript is actually fine too)